# Karatsuba Multiplication with Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, karatsuba

I am trying to implement Karatsuba Multiplication in Python. Unfortunately, my code is failing on 64 digit test cases (curriculum I am working on) because I start yielding negative numbers for my gauss calculations. I included my code below and was wondering if anyone would be able to offer some guidance what I may be missing.

Additionally, I am intentionally storing these large numbers as strings because the whole point of this assignment was to challenge myself calling recursion. I believe Python is able to handle these large numbers automatically, but it would defeat the whole challenging part of this assignment.

The input are both 64 digits.

```
def karatsuba(input1, input2):
    first_number = len(input1)
    second_number = len(input2)

    # base case
    if first_number <= 2:
        return str(int(input1) * int(input2))

    else:
        # first half
        # changing the divider from round(first_number/2) to first_number // 2 yielded different results.
        if first_number % 2 == 1:
            add_zero = first_number + 1
        else:
            add_zero = first_number

        divider_a = first_number // 2
        a = input1[:divider_a]
        b = input1[divider_a:]
        print("a: " + a)
        print("b: " + b)

        # second half
        divider_b = second_number // 2
        c = input2[:divider_b]
        d = input2[divider_b:]
        print("c: " + c)
        print("d: " + d)

    # recursive
    ac = karatsuba(a, c)
    print("ac: " + ac)

    bd = karatsuba(b, d)
    print("bd: " + bd)

    ad = karatsuba(a, d)
    print("ad: " + ad)
    bc = karatsuba(b, c)
    print("bc: " + bc)

    # for subtraction, you add the negative.

    def addition(input_a, input_b):
        return str(int(input_a) + int(input_b))

    ab_cd = karatsuba(addition(a, b), addition(c, d))
    print("ab_cd: " + ab_cd)

    gauss = addition(addition(ab_cd, "-"+ac), "-"+bd)

    print("gauss: " + gauss)

    merge1 = ac + "0"*add_zero
    print("merge1: " + merge1)
    merge2 = gauss + str(("0"*(add_zero//2)))
    print("merge2: " + merge2)
    merge3 = bd
    return (addition(addition(merge1, merge2), merge3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_a, input_b = map(str, input().split())
    print(karatsuba(input_a, input_b))
```

Comment: When asking questions on stackoverflow, I recommend to avoid relying on user input, such as `input_a, input_b = map(str, input().split())`. Instead, hardcode a list of values and explicitly call `karatsuba` on them. It makes it much easier to present the errors you've noticed, and other stackoverflow users can easily reproduce your issue. Then, instead of a vague *"Unfortunately, my code is failing on 64 digit test cases"*, you can say something explicit such as *"Here are a few test cases, with the expected result and the actual result from the code."*

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code, it blows up with an `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error.  And you can see in your debugging output one issue:

```
a: 1
b: 02
c: 
d: 2
```

Empty strings are getting passed around as numbers.  And leading zeros are causing incorrect splitting of strings.

I believe your initial, primary problem is splitting the two inputs by *different* bases from the *left*.  They should be split by the *same* base from the *right*.  Otherwise, doing math on them makes no sense.  you also include the sign of the number in the base calculation!

I also believe your subtration logic is *fragile*.  It works for subtracting a small number from a much larger one, but otherwise, you run the risk of concatenating a "-" on an already negative number, getting results like "--4" that `int()` can't handle.

Finally, I believe there are mistakes in your math. It's further complicated by values you compute but never use (e.g. `ad` and `bc`).

Below is my rework of your code following the explanation of [the Karatsuba algorithm in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) which I tested on their example and a pair of random 64 digit numbers.  It is still flawed, e.g. number signs can still effect base calculation, subtraction is still fragile, etc.  But basically demonstrates the algorithm:

```
def karatsuba(input1, input2):
    print("input1: {}, input2: {}".format(input1, input2))
    length1 = len(input1)
    length2 = len(input2)

    # base case
    if length1 <= 2 or length2 <= 2:
        return str(int(input1) * int(input2))

    # first half
    base_length = min(length1, length2) // 2

    divider_a = length1 - base_length
    high1, low1 = input1[:divider_a], input1[divider_a:]

    while len(low1) > 1 and low1[0] == '0':
        low1 = low1[1:]  # remove leading zeros

    print("high1:", high1, "low1:", low1)

    # second half
    divider_b = length2 - base_length
    high2, low2 = input2[:divider_b], input2[divider_b:]

    while len(low2) > 1 and low2[0] == '0':
        low2 = low2[1:]  # remove leading zeros

    print("high2:", high2, "low2:", low2)

    # recursive
    z0 = karatsuba(low1, low2)
    print("z0:", z0)

    z2 = karatsuba(high1, high2)
    print("z2:", z2)

    def addition(input_a, input_b):
        return str(int(input_a) + int(input_b))

    # The four multiplication Babbage solution:
    #
    # z1 = addition(karatsuba(low1, high2), karatsuba(high1, low2))
    # print("z1:", z1)

    # The three multiplication Gauss solution:
    # This approach may cause overflow, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm for a work around
    # For subtraction, you add the negative.

    z1 = addition(addition(karatsuba(addition(high1, low1), addition(high2, low2)), f"-{z2}"), f"-{z0}")
    print("z1: ", z1)

    return addition(addition(z2 + "0" * (base_length * 2), z1 + "0" * (base_length * 1)), z0 + "0" * (base_length * 0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = "7392297780844983031173686285210463614020982285096612188770501341"
    b = "4688026175884269750785003351250107609139231296129030834139247897"

    print(karatsuba(a, b))
```